# Anyone else have a noise issue with thicker (~9mm) picks?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, noise, picks

I watched a video from Rob Scallon on Purple Plectrums, and in his video they looked and sounded great. However, I purchased one of theirs, a 9mm model and I was very confused. I loved the feel of it, and it sounded great at first, but as I kept playing I noticed there was a very noticeable "plinking" noise whenever I hit notes in quick succession. I tried on two different guitars, I tried playing in different positions between both pickups, and I made sure I was picking at the very thinnest part of the edge that I possibly could, but the issue still persisted. I Googled the issue and found absolutely nothing. So I contacted Purple Plectrum (with an audio clip of what it sounded like) and they said they had *never heard of anything like that happening*, so they sent me a new, upgraded hand-made one. This one feels even better, but the same exact issue persists. I contacted them again, and they said I might just not understand how to play it/it might not be the right pick for me, and they linked the exact Rob Scallion that made me want it in the first place! It's not like I'm even hitting the strings in very quick succession either, I'm playing at a pretty reasonable speed, probably no faster than Rob plays in the very video, yet I hear nothing like it in his video. So does anyone have any experience with Purple Plectrums and thick picks, or have a similar experience with picks making a noise when you repeatedly hit a string? I spent $30 and I really like the feel of it so I want to be able to use it.

Edit: I should mention the String Gauge is Ernie Ball Regular .010-.046 and the strings are raised about 2.75mm above the 14th fret.

Comment: To me a bit of a harder attack is normal with less flexible picks, and part of the attraction of using them...

Comment: Btw do you hear this noise through the amp, or just acoustically?

Comment: Is everybody missing out on a decimal point here? 9mm is nearly the thickness of your finger.

Comment: @Tetsujin They really are 9mm. And they come with a 5-year warranty. https://www.purpleplectrums.com/collections/mid-tech/products/scallon-1

Comment: Wow! Totally bizarre! ;) Warranty aside, I have a Jim Dunlop .60mm I've had since the late 70s ;)

Comment: Can you add a link to the same audio file that you sent to the pick makers?

Comment: Sure, do I need to upload it privately on soundcloud then link it or something? I'll do it when I get home from work.

Comment: @Tetsujin they're really 9mm. not the tip you play with obviously but the part you hold. And they feel great.

Comment: @ToddWilcox here's a link to the sound https://soundcloud.com/connor-gette/string-plinking-sound/s-Mne00

Comment: It is possible that your picking technique needs improvement.  When you change gear (and picks are gear) you need to adjust to the new feel.  Now all your muscle memory is set to give a good attack with another pick.  New thickness, material, flexion, etc will require an adjustment period.  I use very thick picks (though not as thick as yours).  I have noticed similar issues when switching pick style and string gauge.  But with some practice it clears up.

Comment: @ggcg I understand, and I hope you're correct, however I don't understand how I could possibly play it any differently. Unless I stop hitting the same string in succession, which would seriously limit how I play.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that but there are subtle changes that can make a difference.

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: The frequency of the plinky sound suggests that it is the part of the string between the bridge and the pick vibrating. Either the pick is in contact with the string too long before the actual pluck, or maybe you're hitting the string next to it. Can you change the pitch of the plinky sound by playing closer to or further away from the bridge?

Comment: @YourUncleBob if I play very close to the bridge, then the plinking sound almost disappears. Obviously I can't just play there all the time, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to diagnose with a video of your picking so we can see what your hand is doing, but from listening I have a couple of suggestions you can try.

It sounds like the pick may be noticeably stopping the vibration of the string as you bring it down for the next attack, with the string vibrating against the mass of the bigger pick. Try bringing the pick in at a slightly off angle from the string, making sure you are not picking with the face of the pick in parallel to the string. The Purple is practically a four faced pick, so you may have a little trouble not causing the problem with the other side, but try to get one edge of the pick to hit the string first.

It sounds like you are picking in all down pick motion. I know that's a style with a specific sound, but if the music doesn't call for it you could try using a down up down up picking and see if a softer attack clears it up.

You could also try picking in a more circular motion to the string. Instead of picking down and in to the next string, come up and away from the string and circle over the top to start your next down stroke, keeping your wrist as flexible and relaxed as possible.

A combination of a different angle of attack and a lighter away stroke may help keep the pick from catching the string vibration on your next attack.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really helpful comment. I'll try your suggestions, and if the issue persists I guess I'll use my webcam to record myself while I play, as I have no friends.